# Javascript Array / jQuery .data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, prototypejs

I've an attached data which contain an ID list used like this :

```
//Create
$('#element').data('list', new Array());
//Add a value into data
$('#element').data('list').push(id);
//Remove an element
var inArray = jQuery.inArray(id, jQuery('#element').data('list'));
if(inArray != -1) jQuery('#element').data('list').splice(inArray, 1);
```

I want to send this data to PHP throught an Ajax call using prototype.
It looks like this : *`[1,2,3]` will be replace by `jQuery('#filmsList').data('listFilms')`*

```
ajax: {
   method: 'post',
   parameters : {'values' : [1,2,3]},
   evalScripts: true,
}
```

And the posted params are :

```
values  1
values  2
values  3
```

So in PHP I retrieve only

```
array(1) {
  ["values"] => string(1) "3"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

And If I don't put my array in the object `parameters : [1,2,3]`, I retrieve a lot of functions attached to my data like this :

```
array(40) {
[0] => string(6) "1"
[1] => string(6) "2"
[2] => string(6) "3"
["each"] => string(233) "function each(iterator, context) {
  var index = 0;
  try {
    this._each(function(value) {
      iterator.call(context, value, index++);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    if (e != $break) throw e;
 }
  return this;
}"
["eachSlice"] => string(291) "function eachSlice(number, iterator, context) {
 var index = -number, slices = [], array = this.toArray();
  if (number < 1) return array;
  while ((index += number) < array.length)
   slices.push(array.slice(index, index+number));
  return slices.collect(iterator, context);
}"
["all"] =>......
```

Comment: get rid of jQuery.makeArray and .toArray, it already is an array.

Comment: I don't see how that `console.log` works .. isn't `.data('list')` already an array?  How are you calling `.toArray` on it

Comment: @ExplosionPills he appears to have Prototype JS loaded too.  jQuery doesn't like it when other libraries mess with `Object.prototype` and `Array.prototype`.

Comment: `$('#element').data('list').push(id);` will not add to the `data('list')` -- it will retrieve the `data('list')`, add to it, and then let the modified array vanish because you didn't save it anywhere.

Comment: @Blazemonger Are you sure? you can definitely update properties directly using .data, i'd assume using .push would be the same. i'll test ina moment.

Comment: The console.log just before the Ajax call, show me the attempted array of ids.

Comment: `$('#element').data('list').push(id);` works on Firefox. Could I have trouble using other browser? Or can I use it this way ?

Comment: @Explosion Pills In fact, I tried without `.makeArray`, and without `.toArray` but it still show me the good array in js debug console, but some unattempted functions in the PHP var_dump...

Comment: The problem is how the library you are using to perform the ajax request is handling the array. I assume you're using prototype, but you haven't tagged that in your question. Using jQuery to pre-format it may work. `$.param({'list' : [1,2,3]})`

Comment: @Kevin B Yes, I'm using prototype for the Ajax call.

Comment: I just cleaned my question a bit messy...

Comment: @Alnitak Oh, well, I'm deeply sorry for making such a stupid and bone-headed remark. Thank goodness I have your condescending insights to set me straight.

Comment: @JoDev much cleaner, but you've now completely changed the context of the question.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm working hard on this since 4hours. I've just try to resum the issue, keeping all my current test... Is it more understandable?

Comment: kinda.  The problem is you actually have two issues, albeit the latter stems from the first.  The first issue is that you're trying to pass an array instead of an object (of key/value pairs) or a `key1=value1&key2=value2` string.  The second is that in so doing Prototype JS leaks all over the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those functions appearing in your output are from Prototype JS, not from jQuery.

*Something* in the functions you're calling to serialise the array is doing so without checking for `obj.hasOwnProperty(n)`.

However - PHP will be expecting your form parameters to be `key: value` pairs, not as an array.  There's no widely acceptable standard for passing multiple values for a single key, so a *portable* approach might be to manually serialise the array first, e.g.:

```
parameters: { 'values': JSON.stringify(myArray) }
```

and then perform JSON decoding of `$_REQUEST['values']` in the PHP code.

If you know it's only every going to be PHP you can use:

```
parameters: { $.param({ 'values[]': myArray }) }
```

which relies on jQuery to convert the `values[]` key into a format that PHP is known to be compatible with.

Comment: *"I don't know if Prototype JS can do the same."* you can ensure that it does by having jQuery do it. `$.param({ 'values[]': [1, 2, 3] })` I would expect prototype to then just pass the parameters on since it's a string.

Comment: @KevinB actually I'm not sure the `[]` is required - the problem is there's no widely accepted standard for passing arrays like that as CGI parameters.

Comment: And because of that it may vary from language to language. Luckily here we're just using php, where `values[]=1&values[]=2&values[]=3` should be interpreted by php to be an array with three values.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much Kevin B for your help... So I'll use Alnitak option. Thank a lot!

Comment: @JoDev yeah, both are fine.  JSON would be preferable if you wanted to ensure compatibility with other server-side systems that don't understand the `key[]=value1&key[]=value2` convention.

Comment: It was my first question, you really help me. Thank you Alnitak.